# Appendix subsection shown under wrong ToC line

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Currently, my document `main.tex` looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright]{book} %oneside option
\usepackage{etex}
\input{layout}
\begin{document}

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
  \listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
  \bibliography{biblio}

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
  \appendix
  \include{appendix}

\end{document}
```

When I compile my `main.tex` file, I get following result in the ToC:

[image: compiled .tex]

However, the output should of course be as follows:

[image: preferred compiled .tex]

My `appendix.tex` file contains following code:

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
\section{Reference material}
\label{chap:appendix_ref_material}
```

Anyone who can help me to fix this issue?

Also when I add a figure (i.e with caption 'Image 1') to my section 'Reference material' in the Appendix, I would like to see a reference to that image in my list of figures as follows:

A.1 Image 1

Anyone who can help me with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document isn't compilable. What's inside `layout.tex`? You're asking more questions in one post actually

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for the quick response! I uploaded my layout.tex at following location as a code snippet: http://pasted.co/75d4de36

Comment: I had a look into that document... well, please load `hyperref` as the last package, unless you're using `cleveref` or `glossaries`. I think, my answer doesn't need your `layout.tex`, apart from `hyperref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of a working MWE... a possible answer for the ToC problem

- `\usepackage{tocbibind}` will add the ToC and the LoF, LoT, Bib into the ToC --> no need to use `\addcontentsline` etc. here.
- `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}` after `\appendix` will change the numbering (and labeling) of figures then.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright]{book} %oneside option
%\usepackage{etex} Not needed anymore since TL 2015
%\input{layout}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lam94}
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents


  \cleardoublepage
  \listoffigures
  \cleardoublepage

  \bibliographystyle{alpha}
  \bibliography{biblio}

  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
  \appendix
  \chapter*{Appendix}
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
  \section{Reference material}
  \label{chap:appendix_ref_material}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Image 1}
  \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be able, I just copied into my code because I was too lazy to make an `appendix.tex` file ;-)

Comment: Hmm well that's the strange thing.. It doesn't.

Comment: What's the issue if you use `\include{appendix}` ?

Comment: Ah, I see it ... `\section` wanders to `bibliography`. A quick solution: Use `\input` instead of `\include`

Comment: I also tried to rename to app.tex, I thought that maybe there was some kind of conflict with the naming.. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. OK, \input works! Thanks!

Comment: @MoGuL: If you stick to `\include{appendix}`: Move the lines from `\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}\chapter*....` etc to `appendix.tex` then and remove it from `main.tex`

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for the input and quick responses @ChristianHupfer! Everything is running smooth now.